# Test container not able to pass quarkus environment variable

Tags: java, quarkus, testcontainers, quarkus-oidc

Currently, able to pass the DB username and password through test container but when trying to pass the "IfBuildProperty", the value is always null.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please share some code examples so we can understand your problem better.

Comment: Hi Kevin, can you check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71490587/quarkus-environment-variables-issue-with-test-containers?noredirect=1#comment126361374_71490587