# Quarkus environment variables issue with Test containers

Tags: java, microservices, integration-testing, quarkus, testcontainers

Developed the integration tests using Test container. Have few fields as environment variables(Eg: passing it as `quarkus.datasource.username=${SER_DB_USERNAME:postgres}`) in application.properties file.

When setting environment field through test container

```
GenericContainer<?> someService = new GenericContainer<>(img)
 .withEnv("SER_DB_USERNAME", DataLayer.DB_USERNAME)
```

This value is being successfully taken with test containers but

For the below environment variable,
`app.security.enabled=${SER_SEC_ENABLE:true}` defined in application.properties file

```
@IfBuildProperty(name = "app.security.enabled", stringValue = "true")
```

the environment variable is setting through cmd prompt using -DSER_SEC_ENABLED=true, but when trying to pass the same value in test containers, it's always null.

```
GenericContainer<?> someService = new GenericContainer<>(img)
.withEnv("SER_SEC_ENABLE", "true")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Without having more context of the project, I can at least observe, that `app.security.enabled` is a build property rather than a runtime property, so it might be evaluated at build time already. If you start the container with an already built image/application, it is very likely, that the environment variable has no effect.

Furthermore, setting a property on the JVM using the `-D` flag does not result in an environment variable, this is explicitly a system property on the JVM.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. How do I set it as a runtime property? Does Quarkus allow that?

Comment: It for sure does: https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#configuration-sources

Comment: Hmm, I did see that but I want something like "IfRuntimeProperty" instead of "IfBuildProperty" to change it at Runtime. Using "ifBuildProperty" isn't changing variables even at runtime(including system properties)

Comment: The docs explain how to inject runtime properties, so I don't understand the problem, sorry.